# How do I save Java log messages to a file like my Rails log messages?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

I use JRuby and have a Rake task that calls a Java function. This Rake task uses ActiveSupport::Logger to log messages.

```
log = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('log/my_log.log')
log.info 'A message for the ruby logger'
```

Later I call a Java function.

```
obj = JavaThing.new
results = obj.callJavaFunction
```

The `callJavaFunction()` method then does some logging of its own.

```
public class JavaThing {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger('com.stuff.thing');

    public void callJavaFunction() {
       // do stuff
       log.info('A message for the Java logger');
    }
}
```

**'A message for the ruby logger'** is output to my_log.log.

**'INFO: A message for the Java logger'** is output to the console when I run the Rake task.

I cannot modify the Java code. How do I save the message that comes from the Java function to a file?

I've tried `rake my:task > java_log.log` but this only catches console output generated by Rails.

I am using JRuby 1.7.16 and Rails 4.1.4.

Comment: they are conceptually 2 different things and you did not specify what kind of logging framework you're using (what is the full name of the `Logger` class). to bridge the two you will likely need to come up with a "handler" that redirects logs to the Ruby part. alternatively a handler that always uses `System.out` might work with the `>` redirect (instead of saving the `System.out` into a field as most logging such as java.util.logging do).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if there will be any effect on my code due to the fact that Ruby is involved (no experience in that), but you could give the following a try. Do note that I originally wrote it as part of a JUnit test for logging (with @Before), so you will need to do some adjustments to work for your case.

Basically, what it is doing is to also direct the logging to the txt file (Logging.txt in this case) from the console. It will still print to the console.

```
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
public void loggerSetup() {     
    try {       
        fileTxt = new FileHandler("Logging.txt");       
    } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {       
        logger.warning("Filehandler not functional");       
    }       
    logger.addHandler(fileTxt);     
    SimpleFormatter formatterTxt = new SimpleFormatter();       
    fileTxt.setFormatter(formatterTxt);     
}
```

If you want to remove the console printing as well, something similar to the below might work. All of the logging will then be saved in the file only, as the console printing is overwritten and sent to the file.

```
Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");       
Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();      
if (handlers[0] instanceof ConsoleHandler) {        
    rootLogger.removeHandler(handlers[0]);      
}
```